# Infinispan [Add a new Node in a existant cluster]

Tags: caching, cluster-computing, channel, infinispan, jgroups

i want to save my application's data using infinispan when my servers are stopped.``

for your information , in my project i have 4 nodes in my cluster and i want to add a new node which will just contain my data.and i dont know how to add it.

here is my configuration :

```
<infinispan xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:9.4 http://infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-9.4.xsd"
        xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:9.4">
<jgroups>
    <stack-file name="tcpStack" path="${infinispan.configClusterFilePath:ispn/moose-jgroups-tcp.xml}"/>
</jgroups>
<cache-container default-cache="moose-data" statistics="true">
    <transport stack="tcpStack" cluster="mooseCluster"/>
    <jmx/>
    <replicated-cache name="moose-data" mode="SYNC" remote-timeout="1000">
        <state-transfer timeout="1000"/>
        <locking acquire-timeout="1000"/>
        <transaction mode="NON_XA" locking="PESSIMISTIC"/>
    </replicated-cache>
</cache-container>
```

moose-jgroups-tcp.xml:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="urn:org:jgroups"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroups http://www.jgroups.org/schema/jgroups-4.0.xsd">
<TCP bind_addr="${infinispan.jgroups.tcp.address:127.0.0.1}"
     bind_port="${infinispan.jgroups.tcp.port:7800}"
     enable_diagnostics="false"
     thread_naming_pattern="pl"
     send_buf_size="640k"
     sock_conn_timeout="300"
     bundler_type="no-bundler"
     thread_pool.min_threads="${infinispan.jgroups.thread_pool.min_threads:0}"
     thread_pool.max_threads="${infinispan.jgroups.thread_pool.max_threads:200}"
     thread_pool.keep_alive_time="60000"/>
<TCPPING
        initial_hosts="${infinispan.jgroups.tcpping.initialhosts}"
        port_range="0"
        ergonomics="false"
/>
<MERGE3 min_interval="10000"
        max_interval="30000"/>
<FD_SOCK/>
<FD_ALL timeout="6000"
        interval="1500"
        timeout_check_interval="500"/>
<VERIFY_SUSPECT timeout="500"/>
<pbcast.NAKACK2 use_mcast_xmit="false"
                xmit_interval="100"
                xmit_table_num_rows="50"
                xmit_table_msgs_per_row="1024"
                xmit_table_max_compaction_time="30000"
                resend_last_seqno="true"/>
<UNICAST3 xmit_interval="100" xmit_table_num_rows="50"
          xmit_table_msgs_per_row="1024"
          xmit_table_max_compaction_time="30000"/>
<pbcast.STABLE stability_delay="500"
               desired_avg_gossip="5000"
               max_bytes="1M"/>
<pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="false"
            join_timeout="${infinispan.jgroups.join_timeout:1000}"/>
<MFC max_credits="2m"
     min_threshold="0.40"/>
<FRAG3/>
```

can you help me please ?  thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to add a new node to the cluster with the config above, you'd have to update `infinispan.jgroups.tcpping.initialhosts` system property referenced in `TCPPING` and add the new node to the list of initial hosts.

Comment: okey , thank you ! and when i add this new node , it will synchronize with the existants node of course ,so how many times it will take to finish this synchronization, have you any idea ? because im afraid that there will be some treatment of my application before the sychronisation between the nodes  are terminated

Comment: The synchronization is non-blocking. You can still read/write data while synchronization is happening.